Feeling and attachment of not knowing the present moment
I was just meditating, and as I tried to see the breath more clearly, I noticed that there is this resistance again to doing that. When I tried to see that, it seemed to me that there was great pleasure above feeling and a comfortable feeling in the mind remaining as it is and not exerting itself to know the object in the present moment. The pleasurable feeling was very similar to the joy of laziness and comfort, or, for example, the comfort of a warm interior after coming in from the cold outside.
I also noticed a tinge of sleepiness in it, although I just had eight hours of uninterrupted sleep.
Have you noticed this previously? If yes, can you give details on what this is? This feeling is completely new to me, and I think it is an impediment in developing the mind. Thank you.

You might have asked a related question previously. Not sure if they are related....have you tried drinking coffee just before meditating? Does it have any effects?

@Desmon Yes, I have asked this previously because this has been an issue. I think this is also related to the idea of 'Samprajana' , which is, if I understand it correctly, REALLY knowing the object. I once penetrated it & immediately entered what I would believe to be a jhana (merging of object-subject).

@Desmon As for the coffee part, no, I completely abstain from caffeine. I believe it only makes mindfulness weak over time

Trying to see the breath more clearly is craving & agitation. That is why there a comfortable feeling in the mind remaining as it is and not exerting itself to know the object in the present moment.
The tinge of sleepiness is the hindrance of sloth & torpor.

Thank you! I am having difficulty in connecting the dots, can youu please elaborate on why is there comfortable feeling And how is that related to craving and agitation that you mentioned?

The effort to watch the breath is strain/stress. Strain/stress is uncomfortable. To actually watch the breath with clarity, the mind must be gentle, silent & still.

If I were in your position, I would ask myself these questions:

How do I know I am meditating correctly?

Is it possible for me to know what the Buddha meant by "meditation" if I do not have right view?

Do I have right view?  Didn't the Buddha say that one who has right view "knows that he knows"?

If my answer to number 2 is not a 100% "yes", then how can I know I am proceeding correctly?

If everything I experience is and has always been right here, right now, is it even possible for me to be anywhere but in the present moment?

What do I hope/expect to achieve by meditating this way?



Thanks, I will meditate on these, and post updates.

I noticed a similar thread in a few of your questions thus far. Which is why I suggested taking caffeine (either coffee or tea) before your meditation to see if it helps to ward off potential feelings of lethargy. I meant it as an experiment and if you feel uncomfortable with caffeine then just forget it. The thread I am referring to is the somewhat low physical energy that might be affecting you.
In the Godhikasutta SN4.23, it was mentioned that Ven. Godhika was unable to maintain his deep meditation on multiple occasions due to his illness. Thus, it is important as a meditator that we should pay attention to the conditions of our body and the signals that it is giving us. Our body and mind are deeply connected. What affects the body affects the mind and vice versa.
When there is a repeated pattern that appears time and again, it is a cue that there is an underlying cause and we should not ignore it. So, if feelings of lethargy and drifting occasionally appeared in our meditation, it could be due to insufficient sleep the day before. However, if we noticed this lethargy appearing time and again even when we had sufficient quality sleep then we should investigate further. IANAD, the above is just some of my observations. You would need to figure out if this low level of physical energy is indeed affecting your meditation.
